# HABTM with acccepts nested attributes in active admin Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many, ruby-2.0

I am working on an application and i am using active admin. In this application there are question sets and questions models. Questions sets has and belongs to many questions and question has and belongs to many questions sets. Now what happen when i am creating question sets from the admin panel and then trying to questions in the question sets it giving an error

NoMethodError in Admin::QuestionSets#edit

undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class

If i use accept_nested_attributes for questions in questions sets model it is not giving any error but does not work properly.

As i have read that we cannot use HABTM with accepts_nested_attributes. If this is true so what do i do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of ActiveAdmin are you using? If it's 1.0.0.pre, what is the commit ref?

Comment: yes i am using activeadmin (1.0.0.pre) and revision: 7877c8dbf6e7e74787c7294714c655fc60d4a7e3.....